Running slide animation problem Unreal Engine 5
When my character is running and when I press "c" he is doing good animation for slide but the problem is that when animation is over the character is going back to the place where he was before slide animation.
Here is the link to show the animation problem:
Animation problem video
Since I first needed to manually put retarget root on pelvis from one character to another in order for animation to work fine on my character (I used retarget and chain mapping option to make it work). I was expecting now that I got my animation looking good that I wouldn't have the problem which I think has to do with root. I enabled root motion.

It looks like you're asking how to solve the same problem as your previous question. Please don't post multiple questions about the same issue. If you want to change or elaborate on how you described the issue to better attract answers, please edit your existing question instead. This will bump the old question up the feed for visibility, the same as a new post, without fragmenting answers between two different pages. We like keeping all the best answers in one place for ease of reference for future readers.
